# Typeerror during Taylor-approximation

Tags: python, typeerror, taylor-series

For Uni I'm doing this assignment where I have to approximate the difference between the sine function and its n-th Taylor approximation. When running the code plotting these two functions I run into the following error:

`TypeError: ufunc 'add' output (typecode 'O') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'd') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''`

The weird thing (in my opinion) is that the program works fine for `n <= 20`, but when I choose anything above that, it throws this error.

Does anyone know where in my code the problem may lie? Thanks in advance.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

def constant(n, x):
    return np.full(x.shape, (2*math.pi)**(n+1)/(math.factorial(n+1)))

def taylor_n(n,x):
    val = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if i%2 == 1:
            val += (-1)**((i-1)/2)* x**i/math.factorial(i)
    return val

N = [1, 5, 10, 20, 50]
x = np.linspace(0,2*math.pi,100)


for n in N:
    plt.plot(x, abs(np.sin(x) - taylor_n(n, x)))
    plt.plot(x, constant(n, x))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like float underflow. If cast to decimal it works:

```
import decimal

...

def taylor_n(n,x):
    val = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if i%2 == 1:
            val += np.array((-1) ** ((i - 1) / 2) * x ** i / math.factorial(i), dtype=np.dtype(decimal.Decimal))
    return val
```

Inside `taylor_n` function expression `((-1) ** ((i - 1) / 2) * x ** i / math.factorial(i))` has type `float64`, but when `i` becomes greater the type of expression becomes `complex128` and these types can't be summed.

Problem was only while `N=50` (actually, `N>20`), another values calculated correctly. For `N=50` plot is:

[image]

Comment: Inside `taylor_n` function expression `((-1) ** ((i - 1) / 2) * x ** i / math.factorial(i)).dtype` has type `float64`, but when `i` becomes greater the type of expression becomes `complex128` and this types can't be summed.

Comment: I don't think this is quite right: `complex128` isn't relevant here. The issue is that when a NumPy array with dtype `float64` is combined with a Python `int` with value `2**64` or larger, the result has dtype `O` ("object"). (Easy example: try `np.arange(10.0) / 2 ** 64` at a prompt.) And `factorial(21)` is the smallest factorial that exceeds `2**64`, which is why the problem doesn't show up until `n > 20`.

Comment: You could try: when `i=20`, `N=50`, then `((-1) ** ((i - 1) / 2) * x ** i / math.factorial(i)).dtype` gives `dtype('complex128')`. Python 3.8.